# Showing that $gHg^{-1}=H$ implies $ghg^{-1}=h$ for all $h\in H$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can we show that if $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $g\in G$ then $gHg^{-1}=H$ implies $ghg^{-1}=h$ for all $h\in H$?

I tried to use the fact that $h \mapsto ghg^{-1}$ is an isomorphism from $H$ to $gHg^{-1}$ but couldn't see how I can show it has to be the identity map.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. Take any non-commutative (non-Abelian) group and a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$.

If you don't know what a normal subgroup is (you can think of it as the kernel of a homomorphism), it's fine. Take $G=S_3$ to be the permutation group on $3$ letters (which happens to be the smallest non-Abelian group)  and calculate $gHg^{-1}$ for $H=\langle (123)\rangle$.

Do the calculations by hand because it's very good as a practice. For example, you'll see that $(12)(123)(12)=(132) \neq (123)$

Also, you can think of $S_3$ as the dihedral group of triangle. In general, dihedral groups are defined by $D_{2n}=\langle a,b | a^n=b^2=1, bab=a^{-1}  \rangle$.

Comment: (It is not necessary that H be central, for there is no "for all g" in the statement)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Yes, you're right. I first didn't write it, but then I thought I'd better add it if that was what the OP meant. I read the OP's question again and I think I can agree with you on that phrase not being necessary for what the OP is looking for.